# How to insert formula number inside formula?

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

I want to put a formula number inside an \align enviroment. For eaxmple

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,
top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[matrix,arrow,curve]{xy}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage[final]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Предложение}



\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}\label{Prop1}
bla bla follows from bla
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}\label{Prop2}
bla bla bla follows from bla bla
\end{proposition}

$$
\begin{aligned}
bla &\implies bla bla &\ref{Prop1}\\
bla bla &\implies bla bla bla &\ref{Prop2}
\end{aligned}
$$
\end{document}
```

But this doesn't work. I use writeLaTeX. Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: You should use `\[` instead of `$$`. See [Why is \\[ … \\] preferable to $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: You *never* want to use `$$` in LaTeX. Use the `equation` environment for getting a number for the equation.

Comment: I am not sure what it is that you're trying to achieve. But, I made your snippet into a MWE and it works: https://www.writelatex.com/138511jzknxd

Comment: I suggest you to use `\eqref{}`.

Comment: @egreg And what about $...$ ?

Comment: @PeterGrill I added preambule

Comment: @Norbert Not just a preamble, `\end{document}` as well and please fix `! LaTeX Error: Environment proposition undefined` so that people can run the example and see what you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ref` is a text not math construct so you need to locally get into text mode first:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\newtheorem{proposition}{proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}\label{Prop1}
bla bla follows from bla
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}\label{Prop2}
bla bla bla follows from bla bla
\end{proposition}

$$
\begin{aligned}
bla &\implies bla bla &\text{\ref{Prop1}}\\
bla bla &\implies bla bla bla &\text{\ref{Prop2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have removed some commands from preambule and your code strart working. Which command prevent my example to work in writeLaTeX ?

Comment: @Norbert I just removed packages like xypic that were  irrelevant to the question. I added `\text{}` around the ref. I know nothing about writelatex do they have all the packages you used? (just put them back one at a time:-)

Comment: Instead of `\ref`, I'd recommend the `\autoref` command from the `hyperref` package, or writing `\text{Proposition \ref{Prop1}}` to avoid the confusion between the Proposition numbering and numbers within a math environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've checked cases. My code doesn't work because of the command \usepackage[russian]{babel} I can con remove it because my article written in Russian.

Comment: Can you help me with that problem?

Comment: @Norbert adding that causes my texlive2012 to spend ages starting up metafont making kpathsea: Running mktexmf larm0600 (although the final pdf only seems to use type1 fonts so I dont undestand that) anyhow it does work in a standard tex setup with russian babel so you could ask writelatex if they can install the needed package and fonts